# How to do a streaming file upload in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am trying to implement file upload in my project.Is it possible to upload file as stream using `angularjs` ?.I doesn't come across any link that could provide a clear example for uploading file as a stream.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you have a look on ng-file-upload ? if no, google it

Comment: yes i checked it out but can't able figure out clearly.any example code using `ng-file-upload` for uploading file as stream will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**,

1. upload file as stream refer to this link : [File Upload in Angular Js](https://dzone.com/articles/angularjs-file-upload)
2. And this is a module available over github : [File Upload as Stream in AngularJS](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: I don't see anything mentioning a stream upload in the second link.